# »von etwas aus« vs »aus etwas heraus«

Tags: word-choice, preposition

Gibt es eine Faustregel für die Nutzung *von … aus* und *aus … heraus?*
Ein Paar Beispiele:

> Ich arbeite von zu Hause aus.
>
> Aus dem Bauch heraus kann ich sagen ...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Ein Unterschied scheint zu sein, dass wir mit *von … aus* eine wörtliche, meist physikalische Ortsbestimmung vornehmen:

> von zu Hause aus
>
> vom Computer aus
>
> vom Rathaus aus
>
> vom Büro aus

*Aus … heraus* hingegen wird neben der [von Kilian Foth genannten](//german.stackexchange.com/a/34944/2594) wörtlichen Bestimmung einer Bewegungsrichtung oft im übertragenen Sinn verwendet, um eine Aussage in einem geistigen oder seelischen „Raum“ zu platzieren, wobei die angedeutete gerichtete Bewegung einen kausalen Zusammenhang veranschaulicht:

> aus dem Bestreben heraus
>
> aus dem Bedürfnis heraus
>
> aus dem Gefühl heraus
>
> aus dem Gedanken heraus
>
> aus der Überzeugung heraus
>
> aus der Überlegung heraus

Answer (score 6):

Die beiden Konstruktionen bedeuten nicht dasselbe. 'von ... aus' wird verwendet, wenn der Agent an einem bestimmten Platz handelt und dort verbleibt, aber seine Handlungen Auswirkungen auf andere Orte haben. 'aus ... heraus' drückt dagegen aus, dass der Agent den Ort wechselt.

> Ich arbeite von zu Hause aus.

Der Angestellte bleibt zu Hause, aber seine Arbeit gelangt in die Firma, z.B. per Internet.

> Der Bankräuber kommt aus der Bank heraus.

Der Verbrecher *war* in der Bank, ist aber *nach* der Handlung anderswo (ausserhalb der Bank).