# What 'aus' means in this sentence (circumposition)

Tags: preposition

> Von welchem Gleis aus fährt der Zug?

What 'aus' means in this case? 
I reckon that it could be the same sentence without it and it would be correct and the meaning wouldn't change.

> Von welchem Gleis fährt der Zug?

Comment: means "als *Aus*gangspunkt/Start"

Comment: Does this answer your question? [»von etwas aus« vs »aus etwas heraus«](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/34943/von-etwas-aus-vs-aus-etwas-heraus)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

"Von X aus" is a *circumposition*. It works like a preposition, but precedes *and* follows the governed word. It's not useful to ask what either half of it means, any more than to ask what the meaning of the first letter in a word is.

Don't make the mistake of thinking that the right-hand part is redundant just because there is also a regular preposition "von" that could also be used - the meanings are similar but not interchangeable. In particular, von ... aus definitely describes the origin of a directed motion, while basic "von" has many other figurative meanings.

Comment: The fact that the second element _aus_ is not obligatory has been used as one of several arguments that this is not a genuine circumposition like _von X wegen_. The [alternative analysis](https://grammis.ids-mannheim.de/systematische-grammatik/1431) is that _von X_ is a prepositional phrase, that _aus_ is a postposed adverbial modifier of that phrase, and that the whole structure is still undergoing grammaticalization to become a true circumposition eventually. This analysis would contradict your second paragraph.

Comment: @Schmuddi I feel that should be elaborated into a second answer rather than remain hidden in a comment.